# Turn AutoDecode in ASP.NET MVC WebApi off

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

It seems that the FormDataCollection in the ASP.NET MVC Web API auto-decodes the values. Is there a way to turn this off? I am using fiddler to post the following data to my url:

```
.code=2001&Color=Lam%E9%20Purple
```

Unfortunately the color is already decoded and results into the following:

```
Lam� Purple
```

What I was hoping to get is this:

```
Lamé Purple
```

Code used:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostItem(FormDataCollection collection)
{
    int qty = 5000;
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    if (collection == null)
    {
        response.Headers.Add("Available", qty.ToString());
        return response;
    }

    var item = new Item();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in collection)
    {
        switch(keyValuePair.Key)
        {
            case ".quantity":
                item.Qty = Convert.ToInt32(keyValuePair.Value);
                break;
            case ".code":
                item.Style = keyValuePair.Value;
                break;
            case "Color":
                item.Color = keyValuePair.Value;
                break;
            case "Size":
                item.Size = keyValuePair.Value;
                break;
        }
    }

    qty = Repository.GetInventory(item);
    response.Headers.Add("Available", qty.ToString());    
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using some specific request encoding, not UTF-8. So adapt your web.config accordingly using the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
```

or make sure you send correct utf-8 url encoded request:

```
code=2001&Color=Lam%C3%A9%20Purple
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I already tried this. Its the same result.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try sending a properly utf-8 url encoded value of`Color=Lam%C3%A9%20Purple` instead of `Color=Lam%E9%20Purple`.

Comment: I have no control over the request. However I can see that the string is being escaped. I just need to unescape it, but asp.net decodes it before I can unescape.

Comment: Did you try using `<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" />`? You cannot turn off this feature. If the client doesn't respect the standards there's not much you could do on the server.

Comment: Well then I guess you will have to make your client compliant. I am afraid that there isn't much that can be done in this case on the server. You can try playing with different request encoding though but that's the best you could do.

Comment: Whats wrong with: Lam%E9%20Purple? I tried to escape in js the original string and it gave me Lam%E9%20Purple, when I unescape this back, it gives me the original string. It seems fine?

Comment: Have you tried using the `encodeURIComponent` function on the client in order to properly url encode your values?

Comment: Just did and the js result is different.

Comment: What is the result? How is it different? What does `encodeURIComponent('Lamé Purple')` yield?

Comment: I tried it only in JS. Is there an equilant of encodeURIComponent in C#? I dont think that will make a difference even if there an equilant since the value is already decoded. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, there's an equivalent of `encodeURIComponent` in C#. It's the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` method. This method also takes a second argument allowing you to specify the encoding. For example `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Lamé Purple", Encoding.UTF8)` is what you are looking for here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25182/discussion-between-vikasde-and-darin-dimitrov)